# Some convex optimization questions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

1. Is minimizing number of $\{{i : x_i \ne 0}\}$ subject to $Ax=b$ a convex problem? Why is it computationally hard?
2. What is polar cone of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2:0\le x_1 \le x_2\}$?
3. Are $min\{0,x-1,x^3\}$ and $min\{||x-y||:y_1\le...\le y_n\}$ concave or convex sets?

My guess is that 1 is a convex problem. Seems like 2 dual cone is $0\ge x_1 \ge x_2$. For 3, the first is concave because $g$ is a piecewise function of three concave functions (on appropriate domain) but is that enough of a justification? Thanks in advance. Any help please?

Comment: (1) isn't convex because the function you're minimizing is discontinuous. As for its hardness, you can reduce a combinatorial problem to (1) -- in this case it's "exact cover by 3-sets," as laid out in [this reference](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=207987). Exact cover by 3-sets is itself NP-hard.

Comment: What do you mean "a combinatorial problem"? And any intuition for 2 or 3? Is what I said for 3 okay?

Comment: A combinatorial problem is basically a counting problem. I wrote an answer below for the other two that will hopefully give you some hints.

Comment: It turns out that that reference I gave wasn't quite right. I added the comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

(1) : This problem isn't convex because the function you're minimizing is discontinuous.

As for its hardness, you can reduce any number of graph problems to (1) -- I would bet that you could encode an instance of Vertex Cover or some other NP-hard problem as (1), which would make (1) NP-hard.

(2) : The region described is bounded by two lines ($x_1 \geq 0$ and $x_2\geq x_1$). There's a diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone#Polar_cone) that should help you figure out the rest.

(3) : You're close on the first. You need to explain why $x^3$ is concave for this set. As for the second, the region described by the $y$'s is convex (why?). Distance is also convex. You should be able to work from there.

Comment: For 3, why do the $y$'s form a convex set? 

If distance is convex, taking the min preserves that convexity correct?

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late. So you know that the region defined by $y_i \leq y_{i+1}$ is convex. Now take that for all $1\leq i<n$ and you have the intersection of a bunch of convex sets. That's convex. You've got the right idea regarding min of distances.